# How to use common background node for many scenes in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x-2.x

I have a very simple problem, but can't seem to find a definite answer.
I'm making a game that uses the same static background in every single scene.
Currently I simply added the background everywhere, but it sort of seems unnatural, makes some of scene transitions I want really painful to make and eventually I'd like to make an animated background which wouldn't reload with every scene change.

Is there a way to add the same node as a background of all the nodes other than creating a singleton which I'd need to add/remove during every transition?
In other words, can the scenes have transparent background so I can push them over the background scene?

I know that `CCScene` doesn't have `setOpacity` and have seen that some guys advice using `CCLayer` for scenes, but then `CCDirector::pushScene` accepts `CCScene` as the argument.

EDIT.
Ok, now I see that I probably misunderstood the `CCLayer` solution.. does it mean that  the only way of doing it is to change scenes to layers and then adding/removing them from the main scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you one animating/static background and want everything else to change, i would suggest having using only 1 cocos2d-x Scene with your fancy background and all other layers (previously scene) and elements to this scene.

So, technically you would never ever have to transition from a screen .

But, if you find another solution somewhere, do post/share.